# How do i upgrade my current flutter project to its latest dependencies packages and latest version of flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have cloned an old flutter project and need to update it's dependencies and version of flutter. What are the steps needed to do this correctly from what i have gathered in the terminal i would run in this order the following commands:

flutter upgrade
dart migrate
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
dart migrate

i will include my pubspec.yaml:

pubspec.yaml

```
name: vtc_sentry_fl
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 0.2.1+5

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  http: ^0.12.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
  flag: ^1.0.0
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.15
  date_range_picker: ^1.0.6
  intl: ^0.16.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  fl_chart: ^0.9.4

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/vt_icon_logo.png"


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
  - family: Montserrat
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
      - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf
      - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 3):

run `flutter upgrade` command to update flutter and `flutter pub upgrade` to update all dependencies from pubspec.yaml file, and use latest sdk version in pubspec.yaml  file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

To upgrade Flutter run `flutter upgrade` and adjust the SDK version as mentioned by Kartik Patel.

However, in order to upgrade the project's dependencies you have to be careful. I suggest you check out the website of each dependency on pub.dev and read the change logs. Newer versions might introduce breaking changes.

You can run `flutter pub outdated` to list outdated packages and even show their transitive dependencies, you can then update the version of the packages in  `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter pub upgrade` to perform the upgrade.